# How does Lambda no-vpc mode (default Lambda mode) function access other AWS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I know that the Lambda service uses an internal VPC for all the Lambda functions created in default mode (Lambda functions not connected to my private VPCs). This "Lambda service VPC" has access to internet and other AWS services.

So my question is: does it use internet to access to other AWS services (for example, S3) or it uses a private connection through the AWS backbone to access these other services? I would like to know if when I call AWS services from the Lambda this request goes through internet or does not leave AWS network.

Comment: If an AWS Lambda function that is _not_ connected to a VPC accesses another AWS service endpoint in the same region, then the traffic remains on the AWS network. This is true of any AWS service calling another AWS service in the same region.

Answer (score 1):

According to [AWS Lambda Security Overview Whitepaper](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/security-overview-of-aws-lambda/) there's a passage on how requests are handled:

> Traffic within the Lambda service (from the load balancer down)
> passes through an isolated internal virtual private cloud (VPC), owned by the Lambda service, within the
> AWS Region to which the request was sent.

Invocation model:

[image]

Full documentation on Lambda Invoke Modes is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pdfs/whitepapers/latest/security-overview-aws-lambda/security-overview-aws-lambda.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

According to [AWS' FAQ on VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/):

> Q. Does traffic go over the internet when two instances communicate
> using public IP addresses, or when instances communicate with a public
> AWS service endpoint?   No. When using public IP addresses, all
> communication between instances and services hosted in AWS use AWS's
> private network. Packets that originate from the AWS network with a
> destination on the AWS network stay on the AWS global network, except
> traffic to or from AWS China Regions.

If traffic from an instance with a public IP to an AWS service uses the AWS private network then this will most certainly also apply to traffic from Lambdas to AWS services (incl. Lambdas connected to VPC).